# How to disable certain options in a drop down select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

We have two different drop down box's and depending on which one is selected in the first one, options will be grayed out in the second.

http://jsfiddle.net/vUEks/109/

HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
if ($('option[value=2]').prop('selected', true)) {
  $('option[value=5]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle is working. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @robabby No it isn't. It looks like the OP wants the `option` element with a value of 5 to be disabled *only* if the option with value 2 is selected in the first menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to the `change` event of the first `select` element and then conditionally disable the `option` whose value is 5 if the selected `option`'s value is 2:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ty64v0u9/)

```
$('select:first').on('change', function () {
    $('option[value=5]').prop('disabled', this.value === '2');
});
```

---

Depending on your full HTML, you may not actually need jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuLwgxvp/)

```
document.querySelector('.first-menu').addEventListener('change', function () {
    document.querySelector('option[value="5"]').disabled = this.value === '2';
});
```

Comment: Where exactly would I have to put the scripts? In the head? Or does it not matter?